# cakephp: relationship approach for three level associated models

Tags: cakephp, model-associations

Hi I am new to stackoverflow and I am making a medical app, I have certain problem in building proper model.
I have 4 models which are `Retailer`,`Stockist`,`Company` and `Medicine`.
They are all connected by:

```
company has many medicines (hasMany relation)
stockist linked to many company (HABTM Relation)
retailer linked to many stockist (HABTM Relation)
```

now I have to find medicine which are linked to retailer by this 3 level relation i.e. that medicines which are linked to those companies whic linked to retailer linked stockist.
is there any way to achieve this by cakephp?
or I have to make a different retailer to medicine i.e. retailer_medicines model (but there must be very large no. of medicine which linked to a single retailer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to make a new association, since there's already a path to get between the two (albeit a bit complicated).

You'll probably want to [use JOINs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) for this.

```
retailers INNER JOIN retailers_stockists
retailers_stockists INNER JOIN companies_stockists
companies_stockists INNER JOIN companies
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to do this in cakephp way (if possible)

Comment: That IS the CakePHP way - click the link "use JOINS".